# Android gradle fails because of proguard warning

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

Our gradle build fails because of the following proguard warning:

> there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program
>   classes.

Does anybody knows how to find these classes mentioned in the warning?

A bit more logs before the warning occurs

```
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func0 createReplaySupplier(rx.Observable,int); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.Observable'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func0 createReplaySupplier(rx.Observable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,rx.Scheduler); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.Observable'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func0 createReplaySupplier(rx.Observable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,rx.Scheduler); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.Scheduler'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func0 createReplaySupplier(rx.Observable,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,rx.Scheduler); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.Observable'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func0 createReplaySupplier(rx.Observable,int,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,rx.Scheduler); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.Scheduler'
Note: the configuration keeps the entry point 'rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils { rx.functions.Func2 createCollectorCaller(rx.functions.Action2); }', but not the descriptor class 'rx.functions.Action2'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'android.widget.GridLayout' to keep library class 'android.widget.GridLayout'
Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'android.widget.Space' to keep library class 'android.widget.Space'
Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 1 references to unknown class members.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
Note: there were 2459 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Note: there were 2 library classes explicitly being kept.
      You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
Note: there were 40 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 2 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task '...'.
```

Comment: you need to edit the Proguard rules adding the class the library needs

Comment: But which class? I don't see any hint from the logs

Comment: for every library you use, check the readme, they usually include what to write on the file

Comment: But my question is more, can I somehow find out which classes are meant without reading readme or in case readme does not give all informations I need?

Comment: I don't think so, but including what every library says to include, you'll be fine, never had any problem

Comment: So if have 10 Libraries and I get this warning I need to go through all these libraries and see what they need? And if I have 100 libraries? I hope you are not quite right because otherwise it's a bit sad

Comment: try running with `--info` or with `--stacktrace` it might tell you the class

Comment: i tried it but without any success

Comment: Then I think I'm right, and you have to do what I said for every library, good luck :)